# Python script to run .exe program

Tags: python-2.7

I created a python script that run a .exe file. The .exe is located in a directory that the script created, called src the src directory is located inside the script directory that called test. The .exe file should create result .txt file and to put it in the same directory as the .exe file (the src directory). The .exe file does create the result.txt file but instead of putting it in the .exe directory (src) it puts it in the script directory (test).
Whenever i run the .exe manually it creates the result.txt in the src directory as it should.

I use subprocess.call("path_to_exe", args_for_exe) to run the .exe file.

It is specified in the .exe to output the result.txt to the src directory but it doesn't happen when i run the script. someone knows what could be the cause to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is your question and where is your code?

Comment: Have you tried changing the dir to src/ before running the .exe file? 
`os.chdir(path)`

Comment: Your program is running correctly. An executable that outputs a file automatically outputs it in the directory it is run from (i.e. your python script directory) unless otherwise specified within the executable itself. What exactly is your question here?

Comment: os.chdir(path) made the job. thank you Marcelo